# Sharedpreferences and recyclerView

Tags: java, android

I created a program that takes user information including name, age, and date of birth and saves this data through Sharepreferences.
Now I want to display all this information in RecyclerView, but I don't know how to do this.

Can someone tell me a solution to solve this problem?

The challenge for me is that since each user information has an additional ID, I cannot display each information individually in RecyclerView.

Comment: RecyclerView is usually associated with a list, so that each item of the RecyclerView will map to an item in the list. If you have a list of users stored in SharedPrefs, you should instead consider using a database to store the list. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) is a good starting point and its really very easy.

Comment: If you still want to use sharedPref, you should store Id of each value stored in sharedPref and then process those ID, i.e. get each user from the shared Pref and then create a list<User> and pass this list to RecyclerView adapter. But I highly recommend to not follow this, because sharedPrefs have limited storage size.

Comment: @PawanHarariya is totally right. It is not very typical and no clean code to store Object[] or Lists in Shared Preferences. If you want to do it anyways you could just save your Data to a JSON and then revert it if you read the thing. It highly depends on the data Size. You will get along with that, if there are oly <100 Entries. If it gets bigger, this approach will take too long. If you want to make it happen look into GSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why you use Sharepreferences ?? if you have multiple users whom data you will collect then everytime you have to create new key-pair isn't it time consuming although you can just store those data into sqllite database [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-and-add-data-to-sqlite-database-in-android/) and then retrive those data and display it into recyclerview [follow this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6enCz2cY18c)